# After upgrade to 10.15 Cataline /media folder is gone

Tags: mac, upgrade, symlink, catalina

Previously I had used /media to mount remote filesystems.. after upgrading today I find that the directory is gone and / is read only. Is there a workaround for this? The filesystem I had mounted there contains many symlinks with absolute paths pointing to /media/foo/etc